# How to show videos list inside view pager in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-viewpager, mediaelement

I've create a content page inside tabbed page and In the content page i Get videos list from server and show in media element inside list view. All working fine but i want to show videos in view pager for slide videos one by one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have voted to close your question as you haven't shown any attempt in solving the issue your self. Nor are you presenting your findings and debug information. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask good questions that won't get closed. StackOverflow is not a forum where you ask a random question and get people to deliver silver platter solutions for you. Do your own work first.

Answer (score 0):

Add below Namespaces

```html
using Android.Support.V4.View;  
using Android.Support.V7.App;  
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;  
using V4Fragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;  
using V4FragmentManager = Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using V7Toolbar = Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
```

Now, we need to create ViewPager variable and declare the viewpager within the OnCreate(). Before it, we need to change the Activity in AppCompatActivity.

```
//SupportActionBar  
SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);  
SupportActionBar.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon);  
//ViewPager  
viewpager = FindViewById < Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager > (Resource.Id.viewpager);  
var toolbar = FindViewById < V7Toolbar > (Resource.Id.toolbar);  
setupViewPager(viewpager); //Calling SetupViewPager Method  
//TabLayout  
var tabLayout = FindViewById < TabLayout > (Resource.Id.tabs);  
tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewpager);  
//FloatingActionButton  
var fab = FindViewById < FloatingActionButton > (Resource.Id.fab);  
fab.Click += (sender, e) => {  
    Snackbar.Make(fab, "Here's a snackbar!", Snackbar.LengthLong).SetAction("Action", v => Console.WriteLine("Action handler")).Show();  
};
```

For more information follow this link
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-viewpager-tablayout-floatingactionbutton-supportacti/